# Quantmod multiple charts in one pdf

Tags: r, function, pdf, charts, quantmod

I want to draw two charts in quantmod and later on put them in one pdf how to achieve this? Example of a code bellow, in this code i am generating two separate pdfs but how to merge them in one single file?

```
  getSymbols("AAPL", src = "yahoo", from = start, to = end)
  getSymbols("GOOGL", src = "yahoo", from = start, to = end)


  candleChart(AAPL, multi.col=TRUE, theme='white') 
  addMACD()
  dev.copy(pdf, "chart1.pdf")

  candleChart(GOOGL, multi.col=TRUE, theme='white') 
  dev.copy(pdf, "chart2.pdf")
  dev.off()
```

**Any ideas?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
start = "2018-01-01"
end = "2018-04-01"
getSymbols("AAPL", src = "yahoo", from = start, to = end)
getSymbols("GOOGL", src = "yahoo", from = start, to = end)


pdf(file = "charts.pdf")
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
chart_Series(AAPL, TA = "add_MACD();") 
chart_Series(GOOGL) 
dev.off()
```

Comment: But then i have two pages in a pdf file can I have one page and two diagrams on it?

Comment: @Mrowkacala make life easy and better for yourself by using the newer charts `chart_Series` instead of `chartSeries`.  Now you have 1 page.

Comment: Perfect! Appreciate your help!